# jQuery-File-Upload inside fancy box or light box

Tags: jquery, file, uploader

I and many ohthers are wanting to know how would you get the jquery File uploader to work in a fancy box with out using an iframe and is it possible?

I have tried a php include and u can get it to show it just dosnt work properly :(

I would really appreciate any help
Thanks heaps!

here is another post relating to the same issue
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/947

Comment: have you able to find any solution? I am also facing [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10752866/517483).